# How in C++ would you create a method that shuffles the the elements in a Generic Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am to make a Genetic Array class in C++ and in that class I am to give it a method called shuffle that shuffles(mixes up) the elements in that Array

I am using Repl.it to compile my code and this is the link:

https://repl.it/@jamy155/Exam1

In my code, I have 3 files. My main class, My genetic array class, and one other class.
In my array class, I have this method that is supposed to shuffle the array

```
//Array.h//

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> 
class Array {
Element<T>*data;
int size;

  public:
  // sets the size of the array 
  Array(int size){
    this->data = new Element<T>[size];
    this-> size = size;
  }

int length(){
  return this->size;
} 

// add Element to the  Array  

void InsertAt(int i,T value){
  data[i].set(value); 
}

// prints all element in Array 
void print(){
  for(int i = 0 ; i<this->size; i++){
   cout<<*data[i].get()<<" ";
  }

 void shuffler(Array arr[]){
 int n = this->size;

// To obtain a time-based seed
unsigned seed = 50;

// Shuffling our array
shuffle(arr, arr+n,default_random_engine(seed));   // shuffle method 

cout<<"\n";
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    cout<<arr[i].get(i)<<" ";
}
  };
```

This is my main class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Hello World!\n";

Array<int> *arr = new Array<int>(7);



arr->InsertAt(0,6);
arr->InsertAt(1,1);
arr->InsertAt(2,10);
arr->InsertAt(3,3);
arr->InsertAt(4,3);
arr->InsertAt(5,5);
arr->InsertAt(6,4);

arr->print();
arr->shuffler(arr);   //error
```

It gives me an error "exited, segmentation fault".What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question. Eg what is `Array` ?

Comment: `Array arr[]` ? Do you really want to pass an array of `Array`s to the method?

Comment: No you dont. What you pass to the method is a pointer to a single `Array`, but then inside the function you pretend that the pointer points to an array of `Array`s.

Comment: why are you not using `std::vector` ?

Comment: According to your function declaration and shuffle call, you're trying to shuffle arrays, not the elements of your array. Try shuffling your underlying container, Element<T>*data (which should probably be a vector, but this appears to be homework, so maybe that wasn't allowed).

Comment: *"But as you can see when you run my code"* - No... no we can't, because *we can't run the posted code as-presented*. Just look at what you posted. Now consider this from our perspective. That's literally *everything* we have to work with. I copy/paste/compile what you posted (and *only* what you posted) and my compiler will puke errors. There's a reason we need a proper [mcve], and this is it.

Comment: Why does `Array::shuffler` take an array of  `Array` and assumes that the size of this array would be `this->size`? Shouldn't `Array::shuffler` shuffle the elements of the current instance (e.g. work on `this`) instead of shuffling a random array? You might want to spent some time on the drawing board to figure out what this function is actually supposed to do.